# Can a new independent variable be produced from the dependent variable in variable engineering?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, dataset, feature-engineering

I have a question.

I have a data set, my goal here is to estimate player salaries. My variables are salary, number, year, error etc.

I thought of creating a variable such as average salary by making salary / year, but I am not sure if salary creates a problem because it is my dependent variable.Will this be a wrong behavior?

My dataset in the link below:
https://www.kaggle.com/floser/hitters

Comment: No. Your model will be useless since you are just modelling salary with itself. You can easily see why your approach doesn’t work with cross validation. How do you define the salary/year in the test set without knowing the salary you want to predict?

Comment: Ok, I got it.Thanks for answering

Comment: You are welcome! :)